# MVC controller method not getting called from view using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I made ajax call from view

```
function ChangeStatusFunction(associateId, status, comments, caseId) {       
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("ChangeCaseStatus", "PendingCase")',
        dataType: 'html', 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { associateId: associateId, status: status, comments: comments, caseId: caseId },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.somecode').html('');         
        }
    });
};
```

Here is the controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeCaseStatus(string associateId, string status, string comments, string caseId)
{
    IPendingCaseManager pendingMgr = new PendingCaseManager();
    pendingMgr.ChangeCaseStatus(associateId, status, comments, caseId);
    return null;
}
```

The function containing ajax is getting called, i tested that using console log, all values are passed properly

But its not hitting the breakpoint in controller, i.e its not calling controller method

I am getting this error in console after the ajax call

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: That generally means the server is throwing an exception. Do you have any other attributes other than `[HttpPost]` (e.g. `[Authorize]` which may be at controller level). Also, try `data: JSON.stringify( { associateId: associateId, ....}),`

Comment: You're returning null..?

Comment: No I have not made any additional configurations in controller

Comment: @NicklasWinger that is to be done once this issue is resolved

Comment: @vignesh Have you tried calling the method without using the `@Url.Action()` approach?

Comment: I second @StephenMuecke.. Try doing JSON.stringify on your data.

Comment: I removed the type: 'POST' and it worked! not sure of what the issue is though

Comment: Don't remove Type Post instead remove datatype and contentType
It will work

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your data which you are sending by ajax.
Please verify or check error on browser console.

data: { associateId: associateId, status: status, comments: comments, caseId: caseId },